# How to overcome "compile error expected: sub or function" in vba Add ins MS office 2007

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I have been creating an excel add-in that even works with ms office 2007, 2010, and 2013,...
including custom UI

below is my **module code**

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Const VK_CONTROL As Integer = &H11
Sub A_Data_Convert(control As IRibbonControl)
Call A_Data_Convert1
End Sub

Function A_Data_Convert1()
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Selection.Cells
If rng.Value <> "" Then
rng.Value = Chr(34) & "data" & Chr(34) & ": {" & Chr(34) & "text" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & (rng.Value) & Chr(34) & "}"
End If
Next
End Function
```

and also I am facing this issue in ms office 2007 as below
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword

Comment: Strip out the "Alise' term on the API declaration

Comment: @ALeXceL i use this method thank you sir

Comment: Syntax 1 (Sub)

`[ Public | Private ] Declare PtrSafe Sub name Lib "libname" [ Alias "aliasname" ] [ ( [ arglist ] ) ]`

Syntax 2 (Function)

`[ Public | Private ] Declare PtrSafe Function name Lib "libname" [ Alias "aliasname" ] [ ( [ arglist ] ) ] [ As type ]`

Comment: Please check Syntax 2, to declare a Function API.